# Is there a JQuery plugin to represent a United Stated Dollar input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to represent a U.S. Dollar amount input field.  I'd like to have some AJAX feedback to format it with a "$" sign and keep two decimal places (and also disallow letters and non digits.)  Anyone know of an existing project or have a few quick tips to roll my own?

Answer (score 3):

Another [masked plugin](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask)

Comment: Both masks plugins look good, this one has the extra features needed to build a US dollar amount mask.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)?

Comment: Actually, this mask is better written, but doesn't quite handle dollars.